# How can I calculate the right obit period of planets with python?

Tags: numerical-methods, python, celestial-mechanics

Here is my python code which can plot the 2D orbit of Earth, Mars and Mercury with Sun.
However, I cannot calculate the proper orbit of Earth and others .

attempt: I use the $r_\max$, $r_\min$ of orbit, mass of Earth and $G$ constant as input. Using the formula of $T=(a^3/mu)^{0.5}$ to calculate the orbit period.

However,the calculated orbit is around $91667$ which is not around the theoretical value like $365$ days.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse, Circle
import numpy as np

#Set axes aspect to equal as orbits are almost circular; hence square is needed
ax = plt.figure(0).add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

#Setting the title, axis labels, axis values and introducing a grid underlay
#Variable used so title can indicate user inputed date
plt.title('Inner Planetary Orbits at[user input date]')
plt.ylabel('x10^6 km')
plt.xlabel('x10^6 km')
ax.set_xlim(-300, 300)
ax.set_ylim(-300, 300)
plt.grid()

#Creating the point to represent the sun at the origin (not to scale), 
ax.scatter(0,0,s=200,color='y')
plt.annotate('Sun', xy=(5,-30))
plt.annotate('Mercury', xy=(30,-75))
plt.annotate('Earth', xy=(30,-180))
plt.annotate('Mars', xy=(30,-250))

#Implementing ellipse equations to generate the values needed to plot an ellipse
#Using only the planet's min (m) and max (M) distances from the sun
#Equations return '2a' (the ellipses width) and '2b' (the ellipses height)
def OrbitLength(M, m):
    a=(M+m)/2
    c=a-m
    e=c/a
    b=a*(1-e**2)**0.5
    
    return 2*a, 2*b

#This function uses the returned 2a and 2b for the ellipse function's variables
#Also generating the orbit offset (putting the sun at a focal point) using M and m
def PlanetOrbit(Name, M, m):
    w, h = OrbitLength(M, m)
    Xoffset= ((M+m)/2)-m
    Name = Ellipse(xy=((Xoffset),0), width=w, height=h, angle=0, linewidth=1, fill=False)
    ax.add_artist(Name)

    
    
from math import *

EPSILON = 1e-12
def solve_bisection(fn, xmin,xmax,epsilon = EPSILON):
  while True:
      xmid = (xmin + xmax) * 0.5
      if (xmax-xmin < epsilon):
        return xmid
      fn_mid = fn(xmid)
      fn_min = fn(xmin)
      if fn_min*fn_mid < 0:
          xmax = xmid
      else:
          xmin = xmid
    
'''
Found something similar at this gamedev question:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11116/kepler-orbit-get-position-on-the-orbit-over-time?newreg=e895c2a71651407d8e18915c38024d50

Equations taken from:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%27s_laws_of_planetary_motion#Position_as_a_function_of_time
'''
def SolveOrbit(rmax, rmin, t):
  # calculation precision
  epsilon = EPSILON
  # mass of the sun [kg]
  Msun = 1.9891e30
  # Newton's gravitational constant [N*m**2/kg**2]
  G = 6.6740831e-11
  # standard gravitational parameter
  mu = G*Msun
  # eccentricity
  eps = (rmax - rmin) / (rmax + rmin)
  # semi-latus rectum
  p = rmin * (1 + eps)
  # semi/half major axis
  a = p / (1 - eps**2)
  
  # period
  P = np.sqrt(a**3 / mu)
  print(p)
  # mean anomaly
  M = (t / P) % (2*pi)
  # eccentric anomaly
  def fn_E(E):
    return M - (E-eps*np.sin(E))
  E = solve_bisection(fn_E, 0, 2*pi)
  # true anomaly
  
  theta = 2*atan(sqrt((((1+eps)*tan(E/2)**2)/(1-eps))))
  # if we are at the second half of the orbit
  if (E > pi):
    theta = 2*pi - theta
  # heliocentric distance
  r = a * (1 - eps * cos(E))
  return theta, r

def DrawPlanet(name, rmax, rmin, t):
  SCALE = 1e9
  theta, r = SolveOrbit(rmax * SCALE, rmin * SCALE, t)
  x = -r * cos(theta) / SCALE
  y = r * sin(theta) / SCALE
  planet = Circle((x, y), 8)
  ax.add_artist(planet)


#These are the arguments taken from hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/solar/soldata2.html
#They are the planet names, max and min distances, and their longitudinal angle
#Also included is Halley's Comet, used to show different scale  and eccentricity
PlanetOrbit('Mercury', 69.8, 46.0)
PlanetOrbit('Earth', 152.1, 147.1)
PlanetOrbit('Mars', 249.1, 206.7)

for i in range(0, 52):
  DrawPlanet('Earth', 152.1, 147.1, i/52 * 365.25 *60*60*24)
  
plt.show()

rmax=152.1*10**6
rmin=147.1*10**6
epsilon = EPSILON
# mass of the sun [kg]
Mearth = 5.97e24
# Newton's gravitational constant [N*m**2/kg**2]
G = 6.6740831e-11
# standard gravitational parameter
mu = G*Mearth
# eccentricity
eps = (rmax - rmin) / (rmax + rmin)
# semi-latus rectum
z= rmin * (1 + eps)
# semi/half major axis
a = z/ (1 - eps**2)

# period
print('period is',np.sqrt(a**3/mu))
```

Can anyone help me to calculate correctly?Thank you!

Comment: $1/r=a\cos(\theta)+b$ a and b depend on angular momentum of the body in question.

Comment: can you tell more detail, thx

Comment: The semi-major axis is just exactly midway between $r_\min$ and $r_\max$, which gives you $149.6\times 10^6\ \mathrm m$ for the Earth -- no need for semi-latus rectum etc. You have a comment saying "mass of the sun" (which is what you should use to compute $\mu$) but you use the mass of the Earth instead; also, you have neglected a factor of $4\pi^2$. These are things you should be able to work out with a pen and paper (with a calculator to help with the computations). Then you can check your python calculations side-by-side with what you wrote on the paper.

Comment: If you want to get into more detail it will be necessary to write your own work in a way that is readable. Source code (and even attempts to comment it in ASCII) generally don't satisfy this need when the math gets to this level. Try presenting the formulas you are using and the steps you are taking with them using standard mathematical formatting, which you can do using the advice that starts here: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 0):

$H=(1/2)m\dot{r}^2+(1/2)mr^2\dot{\theta}^2+GM/r$

$L=mr^2\dot{\theta}$ by conservation of angular momentum.

$m\ddot{r}=mr\dot{\theta}^2-GM/r^2$

$m\ddot{r}/\dot{\theta}=L/r-GMm/L$

$-\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}(\frac{L}{r})-\frac{L}{r}=-GMm/L$

$\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}(\frac{1}{r})+\frac{1}{r}=GMm/L^2$

Solving the differential equation:

$\frac{1}{r}=c_1\cos\theta+c_2\sin \theta+GMm/L^2$, the equation of an ellipse with a focus at the origin.

WLOG $c_2=0$. Setting $\theta$ to 0 and $\pi$ to find perihelion and aphelion.

Aphelion and Perihelion happen on a straight line so one can solve for $c_1$ by letting $\theta$ be $0$ and $\pi$ and setting the equation equal to closest and farthest distance from the sun.

Given that $L=mr^2\frac{d\theta}{dt}\implies \tau=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{mr^2d\theta}{L}=\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{m}{L}\frac{d\theta}{[(c_1\cos \theta)+GMm/L^2]^2}$ gives you the period.

Of course this breaks up a multibody system inaccurately into a series of two body problems which will necessarily remove some import long term dynamics. To account for that you'll need some non-analytical methods. I seem to recall a leapfrogging runge-kutta approach gives decent results.